# mpi rank not valid in do loop

Tags: fortran, mpi

Im updating a program in fortran to run with MPI and have run into an issue with the rank not showing up properly. In the beginning of this subroutine I call `MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)` and it returns the proper rank until this point:

```
  DO IY=2,NY+1
  DO IX=2,NX+1
   D(IX,IY)=(h_roms(IX,IY)+zeta(IX,IY))*maskr(IX,IY)
   call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)      
   write(out,12) rank,ix,iy
12 format('disappearing?',i3,'ix:',i3,'iy',i3)           
  ENDDO       
  ENDDO
```

NY and NX are 124,84 respectively and the rank prints properly until iy becomes 125, and ix is 3. after that it only prints out as ********* . IT still prints out everything twice (running on 2 processors) but the rank isn't valid, or giving any errors. Ive tried calling MPI_COMM_RANK after the do loop and still nothing. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Fortran, but if you're calling MPI_COMM_RANK as you say you are, that's not your problem. That's pretty much the simplest operation in the MPI library so it's hard to screw that up. I'd suggest that your problem might be somewhere else. Maybe you're accidentally messing with the rank variable?

Comment: That's what I was hoping, but for some reason it stops right near the end of that loop, and that loop only normally contains that one calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran generally prints a sequence of asterisks, your `***`, if a numeric output field is too small to contain the number you are trying to write into it.  Try changing some of the `i3`s in the format statement to `i6` or even `i0`; this last form tells the compiler to print an integer in a field wide enough for all its digits but no wider.

Comment: I changed it to i0 and it gave the rank as `2139095040` for all remaining iterations

Comment: That looks like an uninitialised integer variable to me; something, somewhere is trashing `rank`.  Are your loops running over the edges of your arrays ?  Does `IY = 2,NY+1` set the y-index to one more than the number of `y`s ?

Comment: I changed it from running through `NY+1` to `NY` and it fixed the problem, now my problem is figuring why someone coded it that way for running purely in serial. Thanks for the help.